# What is the best Ruby algorithm to divide an array into groups with a minimum and maximum length?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, partitioning

I have a background job that needs to merge a lot of items together. I want to split this up into multiple "sub jobs" that each merge a subset of the data, and then a final pass that merges the output of all the "sub jobs" together.

A naive way to do this is to split up the data into groups of x elements. The problem is that the last group might have the remainder of 1 element, so it would be a "noop". I want to find the optimal "x" so that the groups are roughly even, and have a minimum and maximum number of elements in each group (e.g. no less than 10 elements, and no more than 20.)

What is a good algorithm for this in Ruby?

Here is some sample output, with a minimum of 10, and maximum of 20. The numbers represent the number of elements in each array.

```
<number of elements in input> => <subgroup 1>, <subgroup 2>, etc. 

5 => 5
10 => 10
15 => 15
20 => 20
21 => 10, 11
30 => 15, 15
40 => 20, 20
41 => 13, 14, 14
42 => 14, 14, 14
43 => 14, 14, 15
45 => 15, 15, 15
50 => 16, 17, 17
55 => 18, 18, 19
60 => 20, 20, 20
61 => 15, 15, 15, 16
```

Basically I want to divide the array into roughly even groups, but with a minimum and maximum number of elements in each group.

Comment: Your issue is not clear. You need to state it fully and clearly.

Comment: Hi @sawa, sorry how can I clarify this? I think it is pretty clear. I need to split an array into optimal subgroups with a minimum and maximum number of elements in each subgroup.

Comment: What is optimal? That is an abstract word unless you define it. What to do when the remainder is other than 1? In your example, you have 5 as subgroup 1, which is less than your minimum 10. I am not sure what you mean by a minimum.

Comment: @ndbroadbent minimum doesn't make a lot of sense for this. Also, shouldn't `41` be `13,14,14`? And `50` be `16,17,17`?

Comment: Indeed, the examples contradict the restrictions

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej Thanks for your feedback. I was taking the floor of each division and then adding the remainder to the last group, and I think that's fine for now. But you're right that `13,14,14` would be a more optimal solution. Maybe I can change my code to do that. (See my answer for an example.)

Comment: To get the number of groups just divide the number of elements by the maximum length and round up, e.g. `61.fdiv(20).ceil #=> 4` (your minimum length is not needed at all).

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, you're right! I didn't need the minimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would approach it like this:

```
# count of original items
count = 61

# max bucket size
max = 20

# decide buckets
groups = (count / max) + (count % max > 0 ? 1 : 0)

# this will be the final result
result = []

# create buckets
groups.times { result.push(0) }

# iterate over original items and distribute them in the buckets
count.times do |n|
  result[n % groups] += 1
end

p result
```

Given the `count` as 61, it prints 16, 15, 15, 15. I've explained the purpose of each statement in the snippet itself.

Comment: Isn't `(count / 20) + (count % 20 > 0 ? 1 : 0)` just `(count.to_f / 20).ceil`?

Comment: This is what I ended up with: https://gist.github.com/ndbroadbent/ba93b017053377b610d15bbf2ec66523

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different version:

```
def divide(c, max = 20)
  groups = (c.to_f / max).ceil
  min_count = (c.to_f / groups).floor

  [min_count + 1] * (c % min_count) + [min_count] * (groups - c % min_count)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at a solution:

```
class ArrayPartition
  def self.partition_lengths(length, minimum, maximum)
    if length <= maximum
      return [length]
    end

    group_size = maximum
    groups = []

    while groups.empty? || groups.last < minimum
      groups = []
      remaining = length
      while remaining > group_size
        groups << group_size
        remaining -= group_size
      end
      groups << remaining
      group_size -= 1
    end

    # Redistribute evenly
    avg_group_size = (length / groups.size.to_f).round
    groups = []
    remaining = length
    while remaining > maximum
      groups << avg_group_size
      remaining -= avg_group_size
    end
    groups << remaining

    groups.sort
  end
end
```

The RSpec test:

```
RSpec.describe ArrayPartition do
  it 'partitions an array into optimal groups with min and max elements' do
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(5, 5, 10)).to eq [5]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(6, 5, 10)).to eq [6]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(7, 5, 10)).to eq [7]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(10, 5, 10)).to eq [10]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(11, 5, 10)).to eq [5, 6]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(12, 5, 10)).to eq [6, 6]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(13, 5, 10)).to eq [6, 7]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(16, 5, 10)).to eq [8, 8]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(20, 5, 10)).to eq [10, 10]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(21, 5, 10)).to eq [7, 7, 7]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(22, 5, 10)).to eq [7, 7, 8]

    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(5, 10, 20)).to eq [5]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(10, 10, 20)).to eq [10]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(15, 10, 20)).to eq [15]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(20, 10, 20)).to eq [20]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(21, 10, 20)).to eq [10, 11]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(30, 10, 20)).to eq [15, 15]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(40, 10, 20)).to eq [20, 20]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(41, 10, 20)).to eq [13, 14, 14]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(42, 10, 20)).to eq [14, 14, 14]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(43, 10, 20)).to eq [14, 14, 15]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(45, 10, 20)).to eq [15, 15, 15]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(50, 10, 20)).to eq [16, 17, 17]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(55, 10, 20)).to eq [18, 18, 19]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(60, 10, 20)).to eq [20, 20, 20]
    expect(ArrayPartition.partition_lengths(61, 10, 20)).to eq [15, 15, 15, 16]
  end
end
```